# Bootstrap 3, full width for nav-pills regarding to its container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a following trouble.

Let's assume I have a container and its width is `950px`. There's a `nav-pills` element in this container, but it has margins on left and right side, but I need to remove these margins to keep this element's width 100% regarding to original container which width is as I said before `950px`. My code looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
        <li><a href="/link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">link1</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="/link2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/link3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">link3</a></li>
        <li><a href="/link4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">link4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And css for `.container`:

```
.container {
    width: 950px;
}
```

So far I tried many ways to accomplish it, for example giving `width: 100%` to pills, but still no luck. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adaccount/z3d9984p/) to give you a better understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3d9984p/1/)
 this happening because of the `padding-left and padding-right` of the container class

**working snippet**

```css
.container {
        width: 950px !important;
        padding-left: 0px  !important;
        padding-right:0px  !important;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
        <ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
            <li><a href="/link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">link1</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="/link2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">link4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: FIrst of all, thank you for dedicating time to solve my issue. Unfortunately this didn't work for me, pills still have margins. I'm gonna check how they'd act if I try negative properties.

Comment: what is the screen at which you are testing?

Comment: Ah, never mind, that's all good right now, your answer helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, your mean like this : https://jsfiddle.net/z3d9984p/2/

so I remove padding to get 100% of width

```
.container {
  width: 950px !important;
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked for me but unfortunately I can't mark both answers as correct :(

Comment: Yeah, no problemo :)